# Is there any limit on how narrow aisles can be?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, transport-category

Sometimes, when I'm flying on the airlines, I'll board an aircraft where the aisles seem incredibly cramped, where it's almost impossible to move past without bumping every seat. I can't imagine how much of a nuisance it'd be for people larger than me! I once saw an obese person a bit stuck between one of the aisles, blocking the way for others to move into the aircraft.

But then I thought about what would happen in an emergency. What if there were numerous large people on board, and there was a fire?

So, are there any limits to how much the airlines can squeeze their planes' aisles?

Comment: as long as they can prove they can get everyone out of the plane in 90 seconds then it's fine

Comment: @ratchetfreak I often wonder if they put "average sized" (*bloody massive*) Americans on the plane for the egress tests, or if they can still find "FAA Standard 170 pound humans" to fill the seats...

Comment: @voretaq7 there was a bit of a scandal on that. A certain US maker of widebody jets was using airforce cadets in running gear for the tests. Eu regulations now require a mix of ages and sizes, although this did result in a few broken legs in the A380 tests.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a transport category airplane with 20 or more seats the minimum aisle width is 15 inches from the floor to a height of 25 inches, and 20 inches width above a height of 25 inches.

> §25.815
>   Width of aisle.
>
> The passenger aisle width at any point between seats must equal or exceed the values in the following table:
>
> [image: Aisle width table]
>
> <sup>1</sup>A narrower width not less than 9 inches may be approved when substantiated by tests found necessary by the Administrator.