# What's the aisle width of long range business jet?

Tags: aircraft-design, cabin-design, private-jets, gulfstream

What's the average aisle width for long range business jet such as Gulfstream G500?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this cabin layout](https://www.flexjet.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/g500-cabin-layout.png) of a Gulfstream G500 found on [flexjet.com](https://www.flexjet.com/jet-collection/gulfstream-g500/), I measured the aisle width at various places:

[image: G500 cabin layout]

The total width is given as 7' 11'' = 241.3cm. The aisle width at the marked positions is then:

1. 63cm (2' 1'')
2. 68cm (2' 3'')
3. 44cm (1' 5'')
4. 51cm (1' 8'')
5. 46cm (1' 6'')
6. 57cm (1' 10'')
7. 50cm (1' 8'')

This would give an average of 54cm (1' 9'') over the measured positions.

Interestingly, the narrowest part (44cm) is less than the FAA minimum for transport category aircraft with more than 10 seats ([Is there any limit on how narrow aisles can be?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/is-there-any-limit-on-how-narrow-aisles-can-be/3069#3069)), which would be 20in = 50.8cm.

Comment: :-) I tried to use that very same image from flexjet but had difficulties with its transparent background. Lucky you. [jetadvisors.com](https://jetadvisors.com/gulfstream-g500-cabin/) gives slightly different dimensions (7,3 ft cabin and 5,5 ft floor), but I doubt them. Oh, and I just helped you over the 8,000 points mark. Congrats.

Comment: @PerlDuck I think the 7.3 ft would be the full cabin from the *inside*, the scale in the used picture is including the fuselage.